# Which tool/programm can create 2d/3d model of human face, based on facial key points (distanse between eyes, etc.)?

Tags: python, 3d, 2d, blender, modeling

I need to control an existing model or create new from the ground, based on 60 face key points.
In other words I have 60 key-positions(face-points) of human face, and I need to draw a new face based on this key-points. Also I need to do it in command-line mode (python language preferred).
Do you know some approaches to do it?

For time I tried to use Blender's python api, but there are some problems connected with failing operator like bpy.ops.translate (I want to use proportional tool) in command-line mode.

Thanks.